# Flutter Appbar UI design

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-appbar

[image]

How to create appbar like this? In flutter default search button I will have to click on the SearchIcon later it will give the search tab but i need it directly like the image posted and also along with the seachbar notification button and navigation drawer.

Edit:
Below is the final working code
with the help of Ravindra S. Patil

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../widget/app_drawer.dart';
import '../widget/bottom_navigation.dart';
import 'package:badges/badges.dart';

// ignore: use_key_in_widget_constructors
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
static String routeName = '/home_screen';
@override
    _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigation(),
    endDrawerEnableOpenDragGesture: false,
    drawer: AppDrawer(),
    key: _scaffoldKey,
    appBar: AppBar(
    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
    toolbarHeight: 80,
    title: Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 20,
        bottom: 20,
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
          10,
        ),
      ),
      child: TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(
                10.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(
                10.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          hintText: 'Search petients,transcript,contacts',
          prefixIcon: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
            onPressed: () => {
              if (_scaffoldKey.currentState.isDrawerOpen)
                {_scaffoldKey.currentState.openEndDrawer()}
              else
                {_scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer()}
            },
          ),
          suffixIcon: Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 8,
                ),
                child: const Icon(
                  Icons.notifications,
                  size: 30,
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                right: 15,
                child: Badge(
                  shape: BadgeShape.circle,
                  badgeColor: Colors.red,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                    5,
                  ),
                  badgeContent: const Text(
                    '2',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          border: const OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(
                10.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `AppBar(
              title: Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 40,
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Center(
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Search for something',
                        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons..waves_outlined),
                        suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.notification_important)),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),`

Answer (score 2):

Try below code hope its help to you. Used `badges` package [here](https://pub.dev/packages/badges) for display notification.

Refer `TextFormField` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html)

Refer `InputDecoration` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration-class.html)

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    toolbarHeight: 80,
    title: Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 20,
        bottom: 20,
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
          10,
        ),
      ),
      child: TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
              const Radius.circular(
                10.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
              const Radius.circular(
                10.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          hintText: 'Search petients,transcript,contacts',
          prefixIcon: Icon(
            Icons.menu,
          ),
          suffixIcon: Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 8,
                ),
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.notifications,
                  size: 30,
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                right: 15,
                child: Badge(
                  shape: BadgeShape.circle,
                  badgeColor: Colors.red,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                    5,
                  ),
                  badgeContent: Text(
                    '2',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(
                10.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
 );
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Comment: Ui worked thanks for that but unable to open drawer i tried to add scaffold key and changed the icon in prefix to iconbutton to and onpressed i tried to call opendrawer but it's not open the drawer

Comment: figured it out should use drawer in scaffold and hide hamberger in appbar using automaticallyImplyLeading: false,

Comment: You want to open drawer to click on menu icon inside textformfield?

Comment: i wanted drawer to open when i click on the menu icon.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SearchList extends StatefulWidget {
  SearchList({ Key key }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _SearchListState createState() => new _SearchListState();

}

class _SearchListState extends State<SearchList>
{
  Widget appBarTitle = new Text("Search Sample", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),);
  Icon actionIcon = new Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.white,);
  final key = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final TextEditingController _searchQuery = new TextEditingController();
  List<String> _list;
  bool _IsSearching;
  String _searchText = "";

  _SearchListState() {
    _searchQuery.addListener(() {
      if (_searchQuery.text.isEmpty) {
        setState(() {
          _IsSearching = false;
          _searchText = "";
        });
      }
      else {
        setState(() {
          _IsSearching = true;
          _searchText = _searchQuery.text;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _IsSearching = false;
    init();

  }

  void init() {
    _list = List();
    _list.add("Google");
    _list.add("IOS");
    _list.add("Andorid");
    _list.add("Dart");
    _list.add("Flutter");
    _list.add("Python");
    _list.add("React");
    _list.add("Xamarin");
    _list.add("Kotlin");
    _list.add("Java");
    _list.add("RxAndroid");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      key: key,
      appBar: buildBar(context),
      body: new ListView(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
        children: _IsSearching ? _buildSearchList() : _buildList(),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<ChildItem> _buildList() {
    return _list.map((contact) => new ChildItem(contact)).toList();
  }

  List<ChildItem> _buildSearchList() {
    if (_searchText.isEmpty) {
      return _list.map((contact) => new ChildItem(contact))
          .toList();
    }
    else {
      List<String> _searchList = List();
      for (int i = 0; i < _list.length; i++) {
        String  name = _list.elementAt(i);
        if (name.toLowerCase().contains(_searchText.toLowerCase())) {
          _searchList.add(name);
        }
      }
      return _searchList.map((contact) => new ChildItem(contact))
          .toList();
    }
  }

  Widget buildBar(BuildContext context) {
    return new AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: appBarTitle,
        actions: <Widget>[
          new IconButton(icon: actionIcon, onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              if (this.actionIcon.icon == Icons.search) {
                this.actionIcon = new Icon(Icons.close, color: Colors.white,);
                this.appBarTitle = new TextField(
                  controller: _searchQuery,
                  style: new TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,

                  ),
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(
                      prefixIcon: new Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.white),
                      hintText: "Search...",
                      hintStyle: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white)
                  ),
                );
                _handleSearchStart();
              }
              else {
                _handleSearchEnd();
              }
            });
          },),
        ]
    );
  }

  void _handleSearchStart() {
    setState(() {
      _IsSearching = true;
    });
  }

  void _handleSearchEnd() {
    setState(() {
      this.actionIcon = new Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.white,);
      this.appBarTitle =
      new Text("Search Sample", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),);
      _IsSearching = false;
      _searchQuery.clear();
    });
  }

}

class ChildItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String name;
  ChildItem(this.name);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new ListTile(title: new Text(this.name));
  }

}
```